# Mui react, I can't size my forms width properly

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styles

So I have two tabs, I used mui tabs for that. For the first tab I display the ingredients, in the second tab I add new ingredients with different forms. I have different fields for each form so whenever I click on one form to open ( I use a mui split button to select and open different forms) , forms open with its width ( sometimes it jumps to center with smaller width, sometimes covers the whole tab). It looks bad. I want to make it a fixed size like 500px then everything looks good. But then for mobile usage or in different small-size components (I want to reuse the who tabs component), 500px doesn't look okay. I need to scroll to see whole form. I tried 100% or fit-content didn't work. My CSS looks like this now.

```
#formContainer {
    width: 500px;
    height:480px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #formContainer {
        max-width:fit-content;
        height:fit-content;
    }
  }
```

I am not good at CSS so maybe I am missing something basic? I try to look for it but I don't even know how to search about my problem. What would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to know exactly what you are going for. What I did on one of my angular projects is using a fixed position with a percent value

```
#formContainer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height:480px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

you also may want to change it to be a class and not an ID since it will be re-used in more than just a single element.

Secondly, you can keep your current values, but also use max

```
#formContainer {
    width: 500px;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 480px;
    min-height: 50%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

For some reason min-height seems to do the same as max-width.
I'm not a CSS expert so hopefully you can get a more precise answer on the hows and whys. I am simply a fellow sojourner suffering in the world of CSS.